# Prototype insert after

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm trying to break up an unordered list containing eight items into two lists, each containing four items.

I figured that `.insert`ing closing and opening tags after the fourth list item should cut it:

```
if(i == 3) {
  $(li).insert({
    after: "</ul><ul>"
  });
}
```

But Prototype gives me the `<ul></ul>` in the opposite order.

```
<ul>
  <li />
  <li />
  <li />
  <li />
<ul></ul>
  <li />
  <li />
  <li />
  <li />
</ul>
```

Is there a simple answer to this one?

Comment: as far as I know you can't insert invalid html code

Comment: those <li />'s look kinda weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JavaScript's MOD operator to see when you are on the first or 4th row.  If you are, create the UL element and then add the LIs to this element.

Something like:

```
if ( i % 4 == 0 ) {
  currentUl = new Element('ul');
  $('li').appendChild(currentUl);
}
```

Comment: Liviu deserves that checkmark, because he (she?) used the same approach and actually implemented a working solution

Comment: @Sean ty and it's a he...last time I checked :D

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I would do it

Html:

```
<div id="list">
        <ul id="original">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
            <li>9</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
var ul = new Element('ul');
$$('#original li').each(function(li, index) {
    if (index % 3 == 0 && index > 0) {
        $('list').insert({
            bottom: ul
        });
        ul = new Element('ul');
    }
    ul.insert({
        bottom: li
    });

});
$('list').insert({
    bottom: ul
});
$('original').remove();
```

Look at a live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/nDgeS/)

Comment: Cheers Liviu, will try that one out.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work like that.

Create a new UL, and move the items to that List:

```
function moveToOtherList(item){
    var myList = item.up('ul');
    var next = myList.next('ul');
    if(!next){
        next = new Element('ul',{style:"margin-top:20px;"});
        myList.insert({after:next});
    }
    next.insert({bottom:item});
}

$$('ul li').each(function(item, index){
    if(index > 3){
        moveToOtherList(item);
    }
});
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nxapS/9/) for a working example

Comment: +1 for a different style. It's good to see multiple working solutions

Comment: @Liviu yeah, but mine's cheap because it only partitions once :-)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know in Prototype but in Jquery you can try this http://jsfiddle.net/nxapS/7/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm stuck with Prototype for this one :-/